# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - ng test --watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am developing an angular-cli app in the following environment:

```
OS: Windows 10
Nodejs: 6.9.2
npm: 3.3.10
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.25.5
```

When I change the code while doing `ng test --watch`, everytime I get the following error:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  541882 ms: Mark-sweep 1369.1 (1393.2) -> 1369.0 (1394.2) MB, 233.9 / 0.1 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  542130 ms: Mark-sweep 1369.0 (1394.2) -> 1369.0 (1395.2) MB, 248.3 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  542384 ms: Mark-sweep 1369.0 (1395.2) -> 1369.0 (1394.2) MB, 253.6 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
  542632 ms: Mark-sweep 1369.0 (1394.2) -> 1369.0 (1394.2) MB, 248.9 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000001EE28FCFB61 <JS Object>
    1: toString [buffer.js:~487] [pc=000002AB3E7A5497] (this=000001E2642F0C41 <an Uint8Array with map 0000001D5B706569>)
    2: /* anonymous */ [C:\dev\{my_project}\node_modules\karma\lib\preprocessor.js:122] [pc=000002AB3E7A9B68] (this=000001EE28FE6659 <JS Global Object>,err=000001EE28F04201 <null>,thisFileIsBinary=000001E...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

`node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng test --watch` solved this problem but ideally I'd like to use just `ng test` command. Other than that, I tried to migrate my project to `angular-cli@1.0.0` and `ng test --max_old_space_size=4096` but they didn't work.

Is there any way to fix this issue just using `ng test` command?

Thanks in advance.